# how to add compass to mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview, compass-geolocation

How do I get the compass to be shown on the screen when my mapview is created.  What is wrong with this code? any suggestions?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.map);



        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mc = mapView.getController();
        myLoc = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
        myLoc.enableCompass();
        mapView.getOverlays().add(myLoc);


        mapView.postInvalidate();

        locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I wouldn't call `enableCompass()` on `onCreate()` (which is where I assume this code comes from, given the `setContentView()` call). Enable the compass in `onResume()` and disable it in `onPause()`, so you don't keep the sensors alive when your activity is not on-screen. And you should not need `postInvalidate()`.

Otherwise, this seems fine. Bear in mind that it will only work on actual hardware.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk) that enables the compass on `MyLocationOverlay` that definitely works, though you will need to substitute in your own `android:apiKey` value.