# Indicate the North in Google Maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, orientation

The problem is that I made an overlay that indicates the current position but now I want the overlay to indicate the orientation of the phone and by clicking it the map rotate to indicate the orientation (just like in Google Maps app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this question [how to add compass to mapview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750897/how-to-add-compass-to-mapview) and its answer

For further questions, Please post what have you tried so far. also, please consider google.
This answer is the first result for the query 'android add compass to mapview'

This might now be exactly what you want, so if it's not, please consider updating your question to explain better.

also check this out [Adding Compass to Rotate MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177426/adding-compass-to-rotate-mapview) it has a sample project there.

EDIT:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/753847/975959
This appears to answer your question.

Comment: i already saw these answers i want the overly that indicate the current position indicate the orientation not just add a compass in the corner of the map!

Comment: You want the overlay that indicates the current location would look like a compass pointing to the north?

Comment: yes that's it look like a compass!! sorry for my english if i didn't explain it well !

Comment: Edited my answer. check it out.